# When are shared library functions loaded into the heap?

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory

(This question concerns only the logical addresses)

I was experimenting with some code where I print out the addresses of different types/scopes of variables to better visualize the process image.

My confusion arose when I printed the addresses a few variables that have been allocated on the heap by malloc, and then also printed the address of the printf function out of curiosity.

What I discovered is that printf was being stored at a much higher address (ie closer to the stack) on the heap than my malloc allocated variables. This doesn't make sense to me because I assumed that the library functions would be loaded on the heap first thing at runtime before any other instructions are executed. I even put a printf statement before any malloc statements, in case library functions were loaded on the fly as they were needed, but it didn't change anything.

Thanks.

Comment: With virtual memory management, there's no reason to have any expectations about the addresses of the stack, heap, and code. And in fact, [Address space layout randomization (ASLR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is specifically  designed to foil attempts at predicting address relationships.

Answer (score 4):

(This answer concerns Unix only.  I don't know how it is on Windows.)

Most shared libraries are loaded into RAM before control reaches `main`, and the library containing `printf` definitely will be.  The functions in `dlfcn.h` can be used to load more shared libraries during execution of the program, that's the most important exception.

Shared libraries have never been loaded as part of the "heap", if by that you mean the region of memory used to satisfy `malloc` requests.  They are loaded using the system primitive `mmap`, and could be placed anywhere at all in memory.  As user3386109 pointed out in a comment on the question, on modern systems, their locations are [intentionally randomized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) as a countermeasure for various exploits.